# Getting java.io.IOException When Trying To Print "Hello World!" Minecraft Forge

Tags: java, minecraft, ioexception, minecraft-forge

I'm new to Minecraft Forge, so this error is kind of odd to me. I set up Minecraft Forge correctly (atleast I'm pretty sure, as there were no errors), and when I ran the `ExampleMod` they gave, it worked fine. I am following [this guide](https://cadiboo.github.io/tutorials/Pre-requisites/), and I set everything up in Intellij. The first few steps worked fine too, until I tried to print `"Hello World!"`. This is the odd part, the actaul program didn't crash, everything was normal, except for the fact that at the bottom it was giving some `IOException` error. I'll try to fit everything happening in this screenshot:[image] My `mods.toml` looks like this:

```
# This is an example mods.toml file. It contains the data relating to the loading mods.
# There are several mandatory fields (#mandatory), and many more that are optional (#optional).
# The overall format is standard TOML format, v0.5.0.
# Note that there are a couple of TOML lists in this file.
# Find more information on toml format here:  https://github.com/toml-lang/toml
# The name of the mod loader type to load - for regular FML @Mod mods it should be javafml
modLoader="javafml" #mandatory
# A version range to match for said mod loader - for regular FML @Mod it will be the forge version
loaderVersion="[31,)" #mandatory This is typically bumped every Minecraft version by Forge. See our download page for lists of versions.
# A URL to refer people to when problems occur with this mod
issueTrackerURL="http://my.issue.tracker/" #optional
# A list of mods - how many allowed here is determined by the individual mod loader
[[mods]] #mandatory
# The modid of the mod
modId="new_items" #mandatory
# The version number of the mod - there's a few well known ${} variables useable here or just hardcode it
version="${version}" #mandatory
 # A display name for the mod
displayName="New_Items" #mandatory
# A URL to query for updates for this mod. See the JSON update specification <here>
updateJSONURL="http://myurl.me/" #optional
# A URL for the "homepage" for this mod, displayed in the mod UI
displayURL="http://example.com/" #optional
# A file name (in the root of the mod JAR) containing a logo for display
logoFile="examplemod.png" #optional
# A text field displayed in the mod UI
credits="Thanks for this example mod goes to Java" #optional
# A text field displayed in the mod UI
authors="Love, Cheese and small house plants" #optional
# The description text for the mod (multi line!) (#mandatory)
description='''
This is a long form description of the mod. You can write whatever you want here

Have some lorem ipsum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis lacinia magna. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed sagittis luctus odio eu tempus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque volutpat ligula eget lacus auctor sagittis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nunc gravida elit vitae sem vehicula efficitur. Donec mattis ipsum et arcu lobortis, eleifend sagittis sem rutrum. Cras pharetra quam eget posuere fermentum. Sed id tincidunt justo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
'''
# A dependency - use the . to indicate dependency for a specific modid. Dependencies are optional.
[[dependencies.examplemod]] #optional
    # the modid of the dependency
    modId="forge" #mandatory
    # Does this dependency have to exist - if not, ordering below must be specified
    mandatory=true #mandatory
    # The version range of the dependency
    versionRange="[31,)" #mandatory
    # An ordering relationship for the dependency - BEFORE or AFTER required if the relationship is not mandatory
    ordering="NONE"
    # Side this dependency is applied on - BOTH, CLIENT or SERVER
    side="BOTH"
# Here's another dependency
[[dependencies.examplemod]]
    modId="minecraft"
    mandatory=true
    versionRange="[1.15.2]"
    ordering="NONE"
    side="BOTH"
```

Everything there looks correct to me. And it runs correctly, it just shows this error at the bottom. What is happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What part of `updateJSONURL="http://myurl.me/" #optional` looks in any way correct?

Comment: I'm new, so I really don't know what it means. Is that causing the error? If so, what should it be?

Comment: You don't have an update JSON URL, but instead of just commenting that line out, you have a bogus URL.

Comment: I commented that out, and now the IOException isn't there. However, whenever I stop the program, it gives a new error: 
    `Execution failed for task ':runClient'.
    > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.242.08- 
    hotspot\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

Comment: How are you stopping the program?

Comment: I'm pressing the red box on the top right, the way I usually stop a running program.

Comment: That red button is the program equivalent of pulling the plug on your computer. Try exiting from within Minecraft instead.

Comment: I got this after exited out of minecraft: `An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`